# How docking RQT_IMAGE_VIEW into a Dashboard

Tags: c++, rqt

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Everybody!

Actually I'm trying to develop a Qt-Python GUI interface for a robot. My objective is to develop a Dashboard who visualizes 2 cameras using rqt_image_view plugin.

For other rqt_plugins based on Python is quite easy to integrate plugins into a Dashboard, but I want to insert the rqt_image_view plugin that is programmed with C++ language. My question is: How I can dock the C++ plugin in my Python based Dashboard?

I hope someone could help me.

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/65174/how-docking-rqt_image_view-into-a-dashboard/) by [creation](https://answers.ros.org/users/4595/creation/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2013-06-14

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can not integrate the existing C++ image_view plugin into a Python rqt plugin - at least not without significant additional efforts.

The rqt framework performs the heavy lifting of mapping between the two languages for you. But it does that on a plugin level. In order to integrate arbitrary C++ code into your Python plugin you would need to create bindings for these parts manually which is a pretty cumbersome task.

You could fill an enhancement ticket against rqt_image_view to also expose plugin agnostic bindings to the core functionality. But since it would be quite some effort to create the Python bindings to make the image widget somehow reusable it is questionable if that will get implemented without someone stepping up implementing it.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2013-06-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1